# visual studio compile time plug-in

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a visual studio plug-in that will track how long it takes to compile and run a project?

Basically I'm trying to make a case to get faster computers for the development department. It seems like it takes a minute or so every time I want to run/debug, so I want a way to track how long ever day/week/month my computer spends compiling.

We are using visual studio 2005, .net 2.0 in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C++, you can turn on build timing, in VS2005, this is under Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Project Settings > Build Timing.  Not sure if this applies to other languages.  This only times each individual build and spits the result to the output window.  If you want to track statistics, then you'd need to parse this and store it somehow.

Comment: +1. It isn't really relevant in .NET anyway, since the build time tends to be so much faster than VC++ ;) The only problem is that the output depends on the compiler language - i.e. on my system, it displays "Buildzeit". This makes parsing a little more complicated if the solution is built on different systems with different regional settings.

Answer (score 3):

You could probally do this very simply using Build Event Macros. One implementation might be to have it execute a small script file which can record the date and time and event to a file, then you can process that file to calculate the ammount of time compiling.

If you have multiple projects in a solution which is preety much the norm these days perhaps a quick custom msbuild task, and you can edit the solution to call that task at the start and end of the process.